# No view found for id 0x7f0a01a2...for fragment

Tags: java, android, view, android-viewpager, android-nested-fragment

I have an Activity A which implements NavigationView.OnNavigationItemSelectedListener that connects it to fragments 1, 2, 3. Fragment 1 has a viewPager and a pagerAdapter which connects it to fragment 4, 5, 6.

I run this and I get an error when Activity A runs fragment 1, it says "No view found for id...for fragment...". I looked it up, but cant figure it out. Can someone tell me how to solve this? Thanks

Fragment 1 is TimeFragment

Activity A is AdminAddNewMerchantActivity

pagerAdapter is DetailsPageAdapter

Below I have the code:

TimeFragment.java

```
package com.vision.lateoclocktt.ui.time;

import android.content.Context;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.content.SharedPreferences;
import android.graphics.Color;
import android.net.Uri;
import android.os.Bundle;

import androidx.annotation.NonNull;
import androidx.annotation.Nullable;
import androidx.fragment.app.Fragment;
import androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView;
import androidx.viewpager.widget.ViewPager;
import androidx.fragment.app.FragmentManager;

import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.ImageView;
import android.widget.RelativeLayout;

import com.google.android.material.tabs.TabItem;
import com.google.android.material.tabs.TabLayout;
import com.google.firebase.database.DatabaseReference;
import com.google.firebase.storage.FirebaseStorage;
import com.google.firebase.storage.StorageReference;
import com.google.firebase.storage.StorageTask;
import com.vision.lateoclocktt.DetailsPageAdapter;
import com.vision.lateoclocktt.R;
import com.vision.lateoclocktt.ui.orders.OrdersAdminViewModel;

/**
 * A simple {@link Fragment} subclass.
 * Use the {@link TimeFragment} factory method to
 * create an instance of this fragment.
 */
public class TimeFragment extends Fragment {
    private Uri imageUri, imageUri2;
    private static final int GalleryPick = 1, GalleryPickBanner = 2;
    private StorageTask uploadTask, uploadTask2;
    private OrdersAdminViewModel ordersAdminViewModel;
    private RecyclerView orderList;
    private DatabaseReference ordersRef;
    private String downloadImageUrl, downloadImageUrl2;
    private TabLayout tabLayout;
    private TabItem tabDetails, tabAddress, tabPrice, tabStart, tabEnd;
    private ViewPager viewPager;
    DetailsPageAdapter pagerAdapter;
    private ImageView inputImage, inputBanner;
    private StorageReference storageBannerPictureRef,merchantImageReference;
    Button saveMechantAddress;
    private String myUrl = "";
    private RelativeLayout rLayout;
    private String currentFragment, currentNavFragment;

    private final String CURRENT_FRAG = "current fragment";
    private String NAV_FRAG = "navigation fragment";
    SharedPreferences sharedPreferences;
    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                             Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        // Inflate the layout for this fragment
        View root = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_time, container, false);
        tabLayout = root.findViewById(R.id.timeTabLayout);
        tabDetails = root.findViewById(R.id.t_merchant_details);
        tabAddress = root.findViewById(R.id.t_merchant_address);
        tabPrice = root.findViewById(R.id.t_merchant_price);
        tabStart = root.findViewById(R.id.t_start_time);
        viewPager = root.findViewById(R.id.time_viewPager);
        pagerAdapter = new DetailsPageAdapter(getChildFragmentManager(), tabLayout.getTabCount());
        viewPager.setAdapter(pagerAdapter);

        //viewPager.onRestoreInstanceState(new );
        storageBannerPictureRef = FirebaseStorage.getInstance().getReference().child("Merchant Banner Images");
        merchantImageReference = FirebaseStorage.getInstance().getReference().child("Mechant Images");

        currentNavFragment = "Details";
        sharedPreferences = getActivity().getSharedPreferences("root_preferences", Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
        //SharedPreferences sharedPreferences = getSharedPreferences("root_preferences", MODE_PRIVATE);
        currentFragment = sharedPreferences.getString(CURRENT_FRAG, "time");

        SharedPreferences.Editor editor = sharedPreferences.edit();
        editor.putString(NAV_FRAG, currentNavFragment);
        editor.commit();


        tabLayout.setOnTabSelectedListener(new TabLayout.OnTabSelectedListener() {
            @Override
            public void onTabSelected(TabLayout.Tab tab) {
                SharedPreferences.Editor editor = sharedPreferences.edit();
                editor.putInt("tab", tab.getPosition());
                editor.commit();
                viewPager.setCurrentItem(tab.getPosition());
                if(tab.getPosition() == 0) {
                    pagerAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
                }
                else if(tab.getPosition() == 1)
                {
                    pagerAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
                }
                else if(tab.getPosition() == 2)
                {
                    pagerAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
                }
                else if(tab.getPosition() == 3)
                {
                    pagerAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
                }
                else if(tab.getPosition() == 4)
                {
                    pagerAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
                }
                else if(tab.getPosition() == 5)
                {
                    pagerAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
                }
            }

            @Override
            public void onTabUnselected(TabLayout.Tab tab) {

            }

            @Override
            public void onTabReselected(TabLayout.Tab tab) {

            }
        });

        viewPager.addOnPageChangeListener(new TabLayout.TabLayoutOnPageChangeListener(tabLayout));
        //tabLayout.setTabTextColors(Color.parseColor("#000000"), Color.parseColor("#ffffff"));

        return root;
    }

    @Override
    public void onCreate(@Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    }

    @Override
    public void onViewCreated(@NonNull View view, @Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onViewCreated(view, savedInstanceState);
        if(currentFragment.equals("Find Food Admin"))
        {
            TabLayout.Tab tab1 = tabLayout.getTabAt(sharedPreferences.getInt("tab",0));
            tab1.select();
        }
        else if(currentFragment.equals("Maps Merchant"))
        {
            TabLayout.Tab tab1 = tabLayout.getTabAt(sharedPreferences.getInt("tab",0));
            tab1.select();
        }
        else if(currentFragment.equals("Price"))
        {
            TabLayout.Tab tab1 = tabLayout.getTabAt(sharedPreferences.getInt("tab",0));
            tab1.select();
        }
        else if(currentFragment.equals("Start"))
        {
            TabLayout.Tab tab1 = tabLayout.getTabAt(sharedPreferences.getInt("tab",0));
            tab1.select();
        }
        else if(currentFragment.equals("Options"))
        {
            TabLayout.Tab tab1 = tabLayout.getTabAt(sharedPreferences.getInt("tab",0));
            tab1.select();
        }
        else if(currentFragment.equals("Brief"))
        {
            TabLayout.Tab tab1 = tabLayout.getTabAt(sharedPreferences.getInt("tab",0));
            tab1.select();
        }

    }

    private void openGallery(int galleryNumber) {
        Intent galleryIntent = new Intent();
        galleryIntent.setAction(Intent.ACTION_GET_CONTENT);
        galleryIntent.setType("`image/*");
        //startActivityForResult(Intent.createChooser(galleryIntent, "Select Picture"), galleryNumber);
        startActivityForResult(galleryIntent, galleryNumber);
    }
    @Override
    public void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data)
    {
        super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
    }

    @Override
    public void onResume() {
        super.onResume();



    }
}
```

AdminAddNewMerchantActivity.java

```
package com.vision.lateoclocktt.Admin;

import android.content.Intent;
import android.content.SharedPreferences;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.text.TextUtils;
import android.view.MenuItem;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.TextView;
//import android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar;

import com.google.android.material.bottomnavigation.BottomNavigationView;
import com.google.android.material.navigation.NavigationView;
import com.vision.lateoclocktt.Buyers.MainActivity;
import com.vision.lateoclocktt.Prevalent.Prevalent;
import com.vision.lateoclocktt.R;
import com.vision.lateoclocktt.Sellers.SettingsMerchantActivity;
import com.vision.lateoclocktt.ui.cart.CartFragment;
import com.vision.lateoclocktt.ui.favorites.FavoritesFragment;
import com.vision.lateoclocktt.ui.findFood.FindFoodFragment;
import com.vision.lateoclocktt.ui.map.MapsUserFragment;
import com.vision.lateoclocktt.ui.orders.OrdersAdminFragment;
import com.vision.lateoclocktt.ui.receipts.ReceiptsFragment;
import com.vision.lateoclocktt.ui.time.TimeFragment;
import com.vision.lateoclocktt.ui.userview.UserViewFragment;


import androidx.annotation.NonNull;
import androidx.appcompat.app.ActionBarDrawerToggle;
import androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity;
import androidx.appcompat.widget.Toolbar;
import androidx.core.view.GravityCompat;
import androidx.drawerlayout.widget.DrawerLayout;
import androidx.navigation.NavController;
import androidx.navigation.Navigation;
import androidx.navigation.ui.AppBarConfiguration;
import androidx.navigation.ui.NavigationUI;
import io.paperdb.Paper;

public class AdminAddNewMerchantActivity extends AppCompatActivity implements NavigationView.OnNavigationItemSelectedListener {


    DrawerLayout drawer;
    NavigationView navigationView;

    private String currentActivity;
    private final String CURRENT_ACT = "current activity";
    private String NAV_FRAG = "navigation fragment";
    SharedPreferences sharedPreferences;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_admin_add_new_merchant);

        currentActivity = "adminaddnewmerchant";

        sharedPreferences = getSharedPreferences("root_preferences", MODE_PRIVATE);
        SharedPreferences.Editor editor = sharedPreferences.edit();
        editor.putString(CURRENT_ACT, currentActivity);
        editor.commit();

        Toolbar toolbar = (Toolbar)findViewById(R.id.toolbar_admin);
        setSupportActionBar(toolbar);
        toolbar.setTitle("Home");
        toolbar.setNavigationIcon(getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.ic_baseline_menu_24));

        drawer = findViewById(R.id.container_admin);
        ActionBarDrawerToggle toggle = new ActionBarDrawerToggle(this, drawer, toolbar, R.string.navigation_drawer_open, R.string.navigation_drawer_close);

        drawer.addDrawerListener(toggle);
        toggle.syncState();

        navigationView = findViewById(R.id.nav_view_admin);

        BottomNavigationView navView = findViewById(R.id.bot_nav_view_admin);
        // Passing each menu ID as a set of Ids because each
        // menu should be considered as top level destinations.
        AppBarConfiguration appBarConfiguration = new AppBarConfiguration.Builder(
                R.id.navigation_merchant_details_admin, R.id.navigation_user_view, R.id.navigation_orders_admin)
                .build();
        NavController navController = Navigation.findNavController(this, R.id.nav_host_admin_fragment);
        NavigationUI.setupActionBarWithNavController(this, navController, appBarConfiguration);
        NavigationUI.setupWithNavController(navView, navController);

        View headerView = navigationView.getHeaderView(0);
        TextView name = (TextView)headerView.findViewById(R.id.username);
        TextView email = headerView.findViewById(R.id.email);

        name.setText(sharedPreferences.getString("name", ""));
        email.setText(sharedPreferences.getString("email", ""));

        navigationView.setNavigationItemSelectedListener(new NavigationView.OnNavigationItemSelectedListener() {
            @Override
            public boolean onNavigationItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
                int id = item.getItemId();
                switch (item.getItemId()) {
                    case R.id.navigation_settings:
                        Intent settingsIntent = new Intent(AdminAddNewMerchantActivity.this, SettingsMerchantActivity.class);
                        startActivity(settingsIntent);
                        break;
                    case R.id.navigation_logout:
                        currentActivity = "main";

                        SharedPreferences.Editor editor = sharedPreferences.edit();
                        editor.clear();
                        editor.putString(CURRENT_ACT,currentActivity);
                        editor.commit();

                        Intent logoutIntent = new Intent(AdminAddNewMerchantActivity.this, MainActivity.class);
                        Paper.book().write(Prevalent.RememberMeMerchant, "false");
                        Paper.book().write(Prevalent.emailKey, "UserEmail");
                        Paper.book().write(Prevalent.passwordKey, "UserPassword");
                        logoutIntent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK | Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TASK);
                        //logoutIntent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TASK | Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TASK);
                        startActivity(logoutIntent);
                        finish();
                        break;
                }
                drawer.closeDrawer(GravityCompat.START);
                return true;
            }
        });

        if(!sharedPreferences.getString(NAV_FRAG, "").equals("")){
            if(sharedPreferences.getString(NAV_FRAG, "").equals("Details"))
            {
                getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction().replace(R.id.nav_host_fragment, new TimeFragment()).commit();
                navView.setSelectedItemId(R.id.navigation_merchant_details_admin);
            }
            else if(sharedPreferences.getString(NAV_FRAG, "").equals("Userview"))
            {
                getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction().replace(R.id.nav_host_fragment, new UserViewFragment()).commit();
                navView.setSelectedItemId(R.id.navigation_user_view);
            }
            else if(sharedPreferences.getString(NAV_FRAG, "").equals("Orders"))
            {
                getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction().replace(R.id.nav_host_fragment, new OrdersAdminFragment()).commit();
                navView.setSelectedItemId(R.id.navigation_orders_admin);
            }
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void onBackPressed()
    {
        if(drawer.isDrawerOpen(GravityCompat.START))
        {
            drawer.closeDrawer(GravityCompat.START);
        }
        else{
            super.onBackPressed();
        }
    }


    @Override
    public boolean onNavigationItemSelected(@NonNull MenuItem item) {

        switch (item.getItemId()) {
            case R.id.navigation_merchant_details_admin:
                getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction().replace(R.id.nav_host_admin_fragment, new TimeFragment()).commit();
                break;
            case R.id.navigation_user_view:
                getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction().replace(R.id.nav_host_admin_fragment, new UserViewFragment()).commit();
                break;
            case R.id.navigation_orders_admin:
                getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction().replace(R.id.nav_host_admin_fragment, new OrdersAdminFragment()).commit();
                break;
        }
        return true;
    }

    @Override
    public void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data)
    {
        super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
    }
}
```

DetailsPageAdapter.java

```
package com.vision.lateoclocktt;

import com.vision.lateoclocktt.ui.brief.BriefFragment;
import com.vision.lateoclocktt.ui.findFood.FindFoodAdminFragment;
import com.vision.lateoclocktt.ui.map.MapsMerchantFragment;
import com.vision.lateoclocktt.ui.options.OptionsFragment;
import com.vision.lateoclocktt.ui.price.PriceFragment;
import com.vision.lateoclocktt.ui.time.StartFragment;

import androidx.annotation.NonNull;
import androidx.fragment.app.Fragment;
import androidx.fragment.app.FragmentManager;
import androidx.fragment.app.FragmentPagerAdapter;

public class DetailsPageAdapter extends FragmentPagerAdapter {
    private int numberOfTabs;
    public FragmentManager mfm;
    public DetailsPageAdapter(@NonNull FragmentManager fm, int behavior) {
        super(fm, behavior);
        this.mfm = fm;
        this.numberOfTabs = behavior;
    }

    @NonNull
    @Override
    public Fragment getItem(int position) {
        switch (position){
            case 0:
                return  new FindFoodAdminFragment();
            case 1:
                return new MapsMerchantFragment();
            case 2:
                return new PriceFragment();
            case 3:
                return new StartFragment();
            case 4:
                return new OptionsFragment();
            case 5:
                return new BriefFragment();

            default:
                return null;
        }
    }

    @Override
    public int getCount() {
        return numberOfTabs;
    }

    @Override
    public int getItemPosition(@NonNull Object object) {
        return POSITION_NONE;
    }
}
```

Errors:

```
E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
    Process: com.vision.lateoclocktt, PID: 4500
    java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.vision.lateoclocktt/com.vision.lateoclocktt.Admin.AdminAddNewMerchantActivity}: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: No view found for id 0x7f0a01a2 (com.vision.lateoclocktt:id/nav_host_fragment) for fragment TimeFragment{fa4480} (b1d4c74f-3fd0-4e61-9d0b-89212a0bd27a) id=0x7f0a01a2}
        at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2665)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2726)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.-wrap12(ActivityThread.java)
        at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1477)
        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:154)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6119)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:886)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:776)
     Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: No view found for id 0x7f0a01a2 (com.vision.lateoclocktt:id/nav_host_fragment) for fragment TimeFragment{fa4480} (b1d4c74f-3fd0-4e61-9d0b-89212a0bd27a) id=0x7f0a01a2}
        at androidx.fragment.app.FragmentStateManager.createView(FragmentStateManager.java:315)
        at androidx.fragment.app.FragmentManager.moveToState(FragmentManager.java:1187)
        at androidx.fragment.app.FragmentManager.moveToState(FragmentManager.java:1356)
        at androidx.fragment.app.FragmentManager.moveFragmentToExpectedState(FragmentManager.java:1434)
        at androidx.fragment.app.FragmentManager.moveToState(FragmentManager.java:1497)
        at androidx.fragment.app.BackStackRecord.executeOps(BackStackRecord.java:447)
        at androidx.fragment.app.FragmentManager.executeOps(FragmentManager.java:2169)
        at androidx.fragment.app.FragmentManager.executeOpsTogether(FragmentManager.java:1992)
        at androidx.fragment.app.FragmentManager.removeRedundantOperationsAndExecute(FragmentManager.java:1947)
        at androidx.fragment.app.FragmentManager.execPendingActions(FragmentManager.java:1849)
        at androidx.fragment.app.FragmentManager.dispatchStateChange(FragmentManager.java:2629)
        at androidx.fragment.app.FragmentManager.dispatchActivityCreated(FragmentManager.java:2577)
        at androidx.fragment.app.FragmentController.dispatchActivityCreated(FragmentController.java:247)
        at androidx.fragment.app.FragmentActivity.onStart(FragmentActivity.java:541)
        at androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity.onStart(AppCompatActivity.java:210)
        at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnStart(Instrumentation.java:1248)
        at android.app.Activity.performStart(Activity.java:6696)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2628)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2726) 
        at android.app.ActivityThread.-wrap12(ActivityThread.java) 
        at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1477) 
        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102) 
        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:154) 
        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6119) 
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method) 
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:886) 
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:776)
```

Answer (score 0):

I figured it out after getting some sleep. In AdminAddNewMerchantActivity.java I changed R.id.nav_host_fragment to R.id.nav_host_admin_fragment and it worked! The view nav_host_fragment really did not exist. I copied it from another file, expected it to work and didn't read the error message properly.